# MiniMagick : Cut circle out of square image

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

I need to transform a square image in circle image with [MiniMagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick).

I know there is a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026935/imagemagick-crop-square-from-circle) with `ImageMagick`:

```
convert -size 300x300 xc:transparent -fill "image.png" -draw "circle 240,90 290,90" -crop 100x100+190+40 +repage circle1.png
```

I've tried to translate :

```
img.combine_options do |c|
  c.draw "circle 240,90 290,90"
  c.crop "100x100+190+40"
  c.repage.+
end
```

I get this stuff, a black circle with my big nose as background image :

[image]

if anyone know how to translate this properly... please !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [Metal](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick#metal):

```
require 'mini_magick'

MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new do |cvrt|
 cvrt.size '300x300'
 cvrt << 'xc:transparent'
 cvrt.fill 'image.png'
 cvrt.draw "circle 240,90 290,90"
 cvrt.crop '100x100+190+40'
 cvrt.repage.+
 cvrt << 'circle.png'
end
```

I personally never try to remember all this domestic method names and always use the metal core approach.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain what each of the lines inside the block achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a website user upload? If it is, you would probably be best using CSS to turn the image into a circle, it would save a lot of server processing and if you feel that in the future you would like to revert back to a square image, it's a lot easier than individually changing the pictures back to the square versions, it's maybe just one line of CSS code.

Comment: Hi Alex, in my case CSS  has no impact. In the same method I get a square image from GitHub, I round it and insert it in an other image, to get a personalized thumbnail